# Return type of check_output function in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm working with the subprocess module in Python and using the check_output function to run a command and capture its output. I want to double check that the output returned by check_output is always a string.

Can someone confirm if the check_output function indeed returns a string, or are there cases where it returns a different data type? If it doesn't always return a string, what are the potential data types it might return, and how can I handle them in my code?

Comment: The documentation says it can be a "bytes sequence, string, or `None`" https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output (See the `run().stdout` documentation)

Comment: Getting StackOverflow to read the doco for you? "By default, this function will return the data as encoded bytes. The actual encoding of the output data may depend on the command being invoked, so the decoding to text will often need to be handled at the application level." And: "If encoding or errors are specified, or text is true, file objects for stdin, stdout and stderr are opened in text mode using the specified encoding and errors or the io.TextIOWrapper default."

Answer (score 0):

`check_output` return bytes by default, but can return string if you set encoding explicitly.

```py
import subprocess
value = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello"], encoding="ascii")
print(type(value), value)  # <class 'str'> hello
value = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello"])
print(type(value), value)  # <class 'bytes'> b'hello\n'
```